# Prepared statements with SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am using Microsoft SQL Server for my database. I was following a tutorial online that was using MySQL, and therefore using the following statement:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPassword);
```

However, sqlsrv does not provide this function. Is there another way to do this with sqlsrv?

Thanks in advance!

All the code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username, EmailUser, PasswordUser) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_stmt_init($conn);

                if(!sqlsrv_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
            }
                else{
                    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

                    sqlsrv_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPassword);
                    sqlsrv_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=succes");
                    exit();
                }
```

Comment: Open the manual please, it is already explained there https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using neither mysqli nor sqlsrv. Start with PDO right now.

If you wanted to do this using `sqlsrv_*` function, the manual suggest something like this:

```
$con = sqlsrv_connect();

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username, EmailUser, PasswordUser) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($con, $sql, [$username, $email, $hashedPassword]);

sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=succes");
exit();
```

I strongly do not recommend using these functions like this. If you can't use PDO, then you should write a database abstraction class to avoid using these functions on their own.